# Hiding symbols from a DSO with DT_FILTER

Tags: c, linker, symbols, ld, glibc

I was recently trying to hide some symbols from 3rd party DSO and came across "--filter" LD option for creating "filter DSO". From the [ld manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld), I have an impression that the dynamic linker will only take into account symbols which are present in filter DSO's dynsym:

> "The dynamic linker will resolve symbols according to the symbol
> table of the filter object as usual, but it will actually link to the
> definitions found in the shared object name."

So it looks just what I need: a way to select which symbols from a DSO take part in dynamic linkage. Unfortunately, it does not work as I expect (this example can also be cloned from [github](https://github.com/tdiff/dt_filter))

Makefile:

```
lib1.so: lib1.c
    gcc -shared -fPIC $^ -o $@

lib2.so: lib2.c
    gcc -shared -fPIC $^ -o $@

lib2f.so: lib2f.c
    gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,--filter,lib2.so $^ -o $@

main: lib1.so lib2.so lib2f.so main.c
    gcc main.c -L. -l2f -l1 -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o *.so main
```

lib1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1()
{
    printf("func1@lib1\n");
}

void func2()
{
    printf("func2@lib1\n");
}
```

lib2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1()
{
    printf("func1@lib2\n");
}
void func3()
{
    printf("func3@lib2\n");
}
```

lib2f.c (filter for lib2.so):

```
void func3() {}
```

Executable

```
void func1();
void func2();
void func3();

int main()
{
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run that test program, I get following output:

```
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
func1@lib2
func2@lib1
func3@lib2
```

One can see that a symbol from lib2 is actually referenced despite the attempt to "filter" it with lib2f.so. What I would like the output to look like is

```
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
func1@lib1   // use func1 from lib1
func2@lib1
func3@lib2
```

Is it at all possible to achieve my goal (hiding some symbols from a DSO) with `ld --filter` option (aka DT_FILTER)?
If not, what is wrong in my expectations/reading of man pages?

Described behavior occurs on glibc 2.34 and 2.17.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27977:

> DT_NEEDED puts the referenced object after the current object in the search scope. DT_FILTER puts it before it. I believe this is the only difference in the current glibc implementation. There is simply no filtering. It has been this way since basically forever

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve the same thing. Looks like this is sensitive to the link order. I moved the `-l1` before `-l2f`, i.e., change your link line in the Makefile to

```
main: lib1.so lib2.so lib2f.so main.c
    gcc main.c -L. -l1 -l2f -o $@
```

With that I get:

```
$ ./main 
func1@lib1
func2@lib1
func3@lib2
```

Comment: Sure it is dependent on linking order. I believe with such linking order there is no need in filter .so at all.